# Best way to refactor current method

Tags: refactoring

I tried really hard to refactor this code , but was unsuccessful. Please tell me how to go about it.    I have been there for hours trying to find solution . I have read some excerpts from book Clean code however, being a beginner I really find it hard to refactor. Sorry, this is my first honest attempt but I am not able to figure out how to make this funtion of size ~4 or small.

```
public boolean[] validateTrueFalse(String[] checkBoxValues) {

    boolean[] answer = new boolean[checkBoxValues.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < checkBoxValues.length; i++) {

        // values are like 1_true
        String[] values = checkBoxValues[i].split("_"); // split each value
                                                        // from my array
        int configId = Integer.parseInt(values[0]);
        boolean isAns = Boolean.parseBoolean(values[1]);

        for (TrueFalseConfigurationModel tm : dt.getTfModelList()) {
            if (tm.getConfiguration_id() == configId) {
                if (tm.isAnswer() == isAns) { // are values from both true
                    answer[i] = true;
                } else {
                    answer[i] = false;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    return answer;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that short doesn't necessarily means better. Many times a longer method can be more readable and will be easier to understand and also maintain in the future. You will sometimes need to look at your code a year or 2 after you first wrote it and it ain't worth a thing if you can't understand it after you made it so short that you can't understand what you meant to do in that method. Of course that the other extreme is also something to be avoided and a too long method is not modular and can be difficult to understand if you want to change only a specific part of it.

In my opinion, that method you wrote is at a good length and doesn't need to be shortened.

But just to answer your question, you can always shorten your methods by dividing them to more methods. for example in your case:

```
public boolean[] validateTrueFalse(String[] checkBoxValues) {

    boolean[] answer = new boolean[checkBoxValues.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < checkBoxValues.length; i++) {

        answer[i] = GetAnswer(checkBoxValues[i]);

    }

    return answer;

}

public bool GetAnswer(string aCheckBoxValue)
{
        String[] values = aCheckBoxValue.split("_"); 
        int configId = Integer.parseInt(values[0]);
        boolean isAns = Boolean.parseBoolean(values[1]);

        for (TrueFalseConfigurationModel tm : dt.getTfModelList()) 
        {
            if (tm.getConfiguration_id() == configId) 
            {
                return tm.isAnswer() == isAns;
            }
        }
        return false;
}
```

Notice how I divided the one big action in the method to smaller actions which created shorter methods. You can then continue in that manner and divide the `GetAnswer` method itself into 2 methods if you can find a logical way to divide it.

Comment: So, when should I say that I have refactored correctly and now I cannot refactor more?

Comment: Well it's also opinion based but I usually keeps methods up to about 50 lines of code. You can sense when a method is too long - when it does many several actions that can be divided over many many lines and you can sense when it's too short, that you begin to have many many small 3-5 lines methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce

```
            if (tm.isAnswer() == isAns) { // are values from both true
                answer[i] = true;
            } else {
                answer[i] = false;
            }
```

By

```
            answer[i] = tm.isAnswer() == isAns;
```

Comment: can this method be more smaller?